# Protobuf RuntimeWarning : Unexpected end-group tag Not all data was converted

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have this utf-8 encoded file from which i need to collect the hexadecimal dump which is protobuf viable  and then feed it to the protobuf.The .proto file works as expected and life is almost perfect.

```
message_content = message_content.replace(" ","")
message_content = binascii.unhexlify(message_content)
```

I convert the string to raw bytes and then feed it to  the protobuf

```
msg.ParseFromString(message_content)
```

from which results the error

```
 RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted
 msg.ParseFromString(message_content)
```

I can't tell if I collect the hex part poorly or if its corrupted.
message_content looks like this:

```
b"87\x00\x00C\x17\x11\x10j\x17\x11\x10\x0c\x00\xc2\x00\x08\xec\xad\xe8\xe0\xf9\x04\x10\x01\x1a\x1f\x08\xea\xae\x18\x12\x14\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x02|\xf0%\x00\x01&\x00\x01'\x00\x01*\x00\x01*\x01\x00\x1a\x00\x1a \x08\xea\xae\x14\x12\x14\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x02|\xf0%\x00\x01&\x00\x01'\x00\x01(\x00\x01*\x02\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x1a#\x08\xea.\x12\x14\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x02|\xf0%\x00\x01&\x00\x011\x00\x012\x00\x01*\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x1a \x08\xea\xae\x14\x12\x14\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x02|\xf0%\x00\x01&\x00\x01'\x00\x01(\x00\x02*\x02\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x1a\x1d\x08\xea\xae\x0c\x12\x11\x01\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x02|\xf0%\x00\x01&\x00\x011\x00\x01*\x02\x00\x00\x1a\x00"
```

Comment: You can check whether binary contents are valid using tools like https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode; I don't currently allow "hexlify" formatted data, so you can't use that string directly (although it does support base-64, which tends to be more common with protobuf if you need to transport it as text, since a lot of the data will end up non-printable). But: the first question you need to ask is: did the data end up the same as you started? the fact that you're removing white-space looks ... suspicious

Comment: If i don't, then I get binascii.Error: none-hexadecimal digit found

Comment: that doesn't change anything, though; fundamentally, *just forget* about protobuf for a second; until you can get the exact same bytes back into message_countent as you started with, *nothing else matters*. So: how did you get this "utf-8 encoded file"? I have a horrible suspicion that it is corrupted *before* you even open it. Ultimately, you should be able to reverse the steps you took to create the file, and get back the bytes; you aren't *showing* the steps you took to create the file, though

Comment: Thing is... I didn't create the file myself, someone else did.

Comment: assuming that the file doesn't contain PII / other privileged data, I'd be happy to take a look and see if it can reasonably be interpreted as protobuf in any way

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Finally I found there is a problem with the data provided by the upstream source. You can also check whether there is a problem with the base64 data source.

Comment: provide some more context please. Maybe some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same err.

the err code is:

```
rsp_serialize =  base64.b64decode(str(rsp)) 
item_info = StrucItem()
item_info.ParseFromString(rsp_serialize)
```

the right code is:

```
rsp_serialize =  base64.b64decode(str(rsp, encoding="utf-8")) 
item_info = StrucItem()
item_info.ParseFromString(rsp_serialize)
```

so you should check your upstream data is ok?